# Calculate image ratio in JavaScript. Result can be approximate to the specification

Tags: javascript, image, aspect-ratio

I would like to have an approximate indication of the picture ratio.
The specifications are 16/9 and 3/1;

The example image i will check has the dimensions of 1281x720px;

To calculate the ratio i use this code:

```
const gcd = (a, b) => b ? gcd(b, a % b): a;

const aspectRatio = (width, height)  => {
    const divisor = gcd(width, height);
    return `${width / divisor}:${height / divisor}`;
};
```

This code works fine.

Well, is there a possibility to check if the picture is closer to 16/9 or to 3/1?
An approximate indication is enough for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```js
const aspectRatio = (width, height)  => {
    const ratio = (width/height)-(16/9) < 0.1
                  ? '16:9'
                  : ((width/height)-(3/1) < 0.1 ? '3:1' : 'out of spec');

    return `${ratio}`;
};

console.log(aspectRatio(1281, 720));
console.log(aspectRatio(606, 202));
console.log(aspectRatio(320, 100));
```

note that the "tolerance" I chose is arbitrary at 10% now, the larger the image dimensions the more inaccurate it becomes (because 10% will be a larger pixel deviation range), so you might want to consider lowering it to your liking...the code above is definitely not elegant =), but for your specific scenario it should work.

A more "elegant" and more flexible solution would be a slightly extended version of your function, something like this:

```js
const aspectRatio = (width, height, tolerance = 0.1, specs = ['16:9', '3:1'])  => {
    return specs.filter((spec) => {
        if ( Math.abs((width/height)-eval(spec.replace(':', '/'))) <= tolerance ) {
            return spec;
        }
    })[0] || false;
};

console.log(aspectRatio(1281, 720));
console.log(aspectRatio(606, 202));
console.log(aspectRatio(320, 100));
```

this would allow to specify

- a) the tolerance level the image dimensions can deviate from the "perferct ratio"
- b) the image ratio-specifications that are allowed

Answer (score 0):

It's a ratio right, so you can check whether your width/height is closer to 16/9 or 3/1:

```js
const width = 1281
const height = 720

const distanceFrom16by9 = Math.abs(1281/720 - 16/9)
const distanceFrom3by1 = Math.abs(1281/720 - 3)

const ratio = distanceFrom16by9 < distanceFrom3by1 ? "16:9" : "3:1"

console.log(ratio)
```